"She nods for him to open the box full of butter biscuits"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 17)
William sits as she reaches into her bag and pulls out a Tupperware box. . . Through the plastic, he recognises his favourites: butter biscuits. . . She nods for him to open the box and sugar coating glitters on the top biscuit.
I can't find any entry of "nod (verb) for someone" but I don't think there is much difference between "nod (verb) for someone" and "nod (verb) to someone", right?

English is very flexible about which preposition to use in many contexts, and sometimes this leads to situations where at least some native speakers assign different meanings to choices which other people think are simply stylistic choices with equivalent meaning. Personally, I think for and at would be 100%  interchangeable in contexts where the nod is intended to instruct the "addressee" to do something, but for me, only for (or no preposition at all) can carry the sense of giving permission. Not everyone will recognize that distinction, though.

...are you mistakenly using "(verb)" where you mean "(preposition)"?

She motions, signals, nods, gestures ... for him to [do something].

@ FumbleFingers - "...are you mistakenly using "(verb)" where you mean "(preposition)"?" - No, I don't think so; "(verb)" refers to the preceding verb "nod". "nod" could also be a noun in other sentences.

This is not an idiom.  In English cultures a "nod" (moving the head down and up) is the body language sign for "Yes". The word "for" can indicate a purpose.  The purpose of nodding is to show that he is allowed to open the box.
So she is signalling, by nodding, that he is allowed to open the box and take a biscuit. She is saying "yes" for his implied question "can I have a biscuit?"
